# Is a bootable USB drive with Yosemite OK for different macs?

Tags: macos, usb, startup

This might be obvious, but probably worth a question: I took my MBP (Early 2011 15"), downloaded Yosemite and created a bootable USB device from which I later clean-installed the OS.

Can I use this same USB device with a different MBP (i.e., Late 2011 13"), or do I have to download the installer again from *that* macbook app store?

I got worried for a second thinking that it might need different drivers, or something like that. Second MBP does not even belong to me, so it will be used with a different Apple ID (i.e., different from the one through which I got my Yosemite).

Comment: Yes it is god to go as many times as you need it.

Comment: @Buscar웃 - well, it's maybe not ***that*** good, but it should be good to go :p

Comment: @Tetsujin it is a Sunday :)

Comment: Having had two similar comments, I trust you enough to accept yours @Buscar (as soon as you post it as an answer) :)

Comment: @Buscar웃 - it was *god* enough for me to +1 :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Yosemite Installer package contains all the divers for all supported models.

You are good to go for multiple uses on multiple systems.